# C# socket refactoring (data sending)

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, refactoring

Imagine that `Byte[] refArchiveData` is around 30-100 mbytes of size. I want to send it to server using `NetworkStream stream` object:

```
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            Byte[] refLengthBytes = new Byte[4];
            Byte[] refArchiveData = null;

            refArchiveData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Temp/Python25.zip");

            Console.WriteLine("Archive data length is {0}", refArchiveData.Length);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            refLengthBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(refArchiveData.Length);

            stream.Write(refLengthBytes, 0, 4);

            stream.Write(refArchiveData, 0, refArchiveData.Length);

            stream.Close();

            client.Close();
```

How i must modify the part of code where i send my archive? Maybe split it by chunks of 256-512 bytes?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) method. This way you don't have to load the whole file into an array (into memory).

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead("<path to file>"))
using (var client = new TcpClient("<server>", <port>))
using (var netStream = client.GetStream())
{
    ...
    file.CopyTo(netStream);
    ...
}
```